# Multiple Checkboxes with same name validator

Tags: php, html, validation, checkbox

I have this form with multiple checkboxes with same name and all of checkboxes are read from a database:

```
echo "<FORM action='check.php' method=POST>"; ?>
<div style='color:#414141; font-size:15px;'>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<input name="check[]" type="checkbox" id="checkk[]" value="<? echo $rows['ID']; ?>"><? echo $rows['checkboxname']; ?>
<BR>
<?php
}
echo "</div>";
echo "<input name='' type='submit' id='get' value='Next'>";
echo "</FORM>";
```

I need a form validation to the next file.When I click on Submit Button(Next),show me the next page only if I checked a checkbox.I preffer a javascript validation method.

Comment: check the values of the $_POST['check'] array in your check.php

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of check.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a click event listener for the submit button and check if atleast one checkbox is checked and submit if true.

Something like below should work,

Try below,

```
echo "<input name='' type='submit' id='get' value='Next' onclick='return validateCheckbox()'>";


<script>
     function validateCheckbox () {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check[]'); //selected by name since OP wanted to select by name

         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
               return true; // found 1 checked checkbox
             }
         }

         return false; //none checked, so cancel submit
     }
</script>
```